# AND logic IF statement in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

```
=IF((=VLOOKUP(D1700,Cullpitsoriginal!B715:B5480,1,FALSE))+(ISNA(J1700)),"CHECK ME OUT","no")
```

By looking at the above formula, I want to return the string "CHECK ME OUT" if the VLOOKUP() returns a non-error value **AND** if `J1700` is `#N/A`, otherwise it should print "no". Can someone please show me the error of my ways as Excel isn't letting me execute the formula as it is giving me the below window:

[image]

Comment: You don't need the `=` before vlookup

Comment: @Raystafarian Cheers dude. Now I've got a `#VALUE!` error. I think it might be to do with the col_index_num parameter in the VLOOKUP. Should it be 1? Considering I don't want it to return anything, other than just TRUE or FALSE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` sums the results of the two if statements.  Use the `AND` function:
AND(firstcondition,secondcondition).  This evaluates to true if both conditions are true.

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(D1700,Cullpitsoriginal!B715:B5480,1))),ISNA(J1700)),"CHECK ME OUT","no")
```

There are probably more elegant ways to produce the same result with fewer nested functions.  I wanted to illustrate how to do the exact logic you described.

Comment: Too few arguments apparently?

Comment: Good catch.  I wasn't paying close enough attention to the contents, just copying and pasting your formula and deleted too much.

Comment: I have given this answer to be correct, although I had to put "False" as the last parameter in VLOOKUP to ensure I was getting exact matches. Thanks!

Comment: Excellent use of the NOT function, real good logical thinking there.